# Capitalize word as you type in emacs/spacemacs (YAS snippet)

Tags: spacemacs, yasnippet

#### Trying the following yas snippet

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
#name : vuex-action
#key : va
# --
[${1:$$(capitalize-word yas-text)}]: ({ commit, dispatch, getters, }, { $2, }) => {
  commit($1, { $2, });
},
```

and get the following errors in messages buffer

```
Wrong type argument: stringp, (integerp #("H" 0 1 (fontified nil face (rainbow-delimiters-depth-1-face))))
Wrong type argument: stringp, (integerp #("HE" 0 2 (fontified nil)))
Wrong type argument: stringp, (integerp #("HEE" 0 3 (fontified nil)))
Wrong type argument: stringp, (integerp #("HE" 0 2 (fontified nil help-echo "Undeclared variable or function 'HEE'" cursor-sensor-functions (js2-echo-error))))
Wrong type argument: stringp, (integerp #("HEL" 0 3 (fontified nil help-echo "Undeclared variable or function 'HEE'" cursor-sensor-functions (js2-echo-error))))
Wrong type argument: stringp, (integerp #("HELL" 0 4 (fontified nil help-echo "Undeclared variable or function 'HEE'" cursor-sensor-functions (js2-echo-error))))
Wrong type argument: stringp, (integerp #("HELLO" 0 5 (fontified nil help-echo "Undeclared variable or function 'HEE'" cursor-sensor-functions (js2-echo-error))))
Wrong type argument: stringp, (integerp #("HELLO_" 0 6 (fontified nil help-echo "Undeclared variable or function 'HEE'" cursor-sensor-functions (js2-echo-error))))
Wrong type argument: stringp, (integerp #("HELLO_W" 0 7 (fontified nil help-echo "Undeclared variable or function 'HEE'" cursor-sensor-functions (js2-echo-error))))
Wrong type argument: stringp, (integerp #("HELLO_WR" 0 8 (fontified nil help-echo "Undeclared variable or function 'HEE'" cursor-sensor-functions (js2-echo-error))))
Wrong type argument: stringp, (integerp #("HELLO_W" 0 7 (fontified nil help-echo "Undeclared variable or function 'HELLO_WR'" cursor-sensor-functions (js2-echo-error))))
Wrong type argument: stringp, (integerp #("HELLO_WO" 0 8 (fontified nil help-echo "Undeclared variable or function 'HELLO_WR'" cursor-sensor-functions (js2-echo-error))))
Wrong type argument: stringp, (integerp #("HELLO_WOR" 0 9 (fontified nil help-echo "Undeclared variable or function 'HELLO_WR'" cursor-sensor-functions (js2-echo-error))))
Wrong type argument: stringp, (integerp #("HELLO_WORL" 0 10 (fontified nil help-echo "Undeclared variable or function 'HELLO_WR'" cursor-sensor-functions (js2-echo-error))))
Wrong type argument: stringp, (integerp #("HELLO_WORLD" 0 11 (fontified nil help-echo "Undeclared variable or function 'HELLO_WR'" cursor-sensor-functions (js2-echo-error))))
Quit [4 times]
```

#### 1. How to fix?

#### 2. Also how to replace space with the underscore in the word as you type?

Comment: if you want to use functions inside sniper tml  set single quat  mark infront: '(func-name)

Comment: I have tried, doesn't work ```[${1:'(capitalize-word yas-text)}]``` it just display the function as the name inside expanded snippet

Comment: Embedded Emacs-lisp code

Emacs-Lisp code can be embedded inside the template, written inside back-quotes (`). The lisp forms are evaluated when the snippet is being expanded. The evaluation is done in the same buffer as the snippet being expanded. https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html

Answer (score 1):

**solution**

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
#name : vuex-action
#key : va
#contributor : Dmitry Semenov
# --
/**
 * $1
 */
[${1:$(upcase (replace-regexp-in-string " " "_" yas-text))}]: ({ commit, dispatch, getters, }, { $2, }) => {
  commit(${1:$(upcase (replace-regexp-in-string " " "_" yas-text))}, { $2, });
},
```